# Vault in Homestead over the port 8200

Tags: homestead, hashicorp-vault

I installed succesfully the [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) in my [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead) VM. I want to manage it in browser. But when I try:

- http://192.168.10.10:8200/ui/
- http://mysite.app:8200/ui/

then I get:

> Failed to connect to 192.168.10.10 port 8200: Connection refused

I tried to configure the port in Homestead.yaml:

```
ports:
  - send: 8200
    to: 8200
    protocol: tcp
```

but it did not help.

In the VM it works:

```
 $ curl localhost:8200/ui/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title>Vault</title>
...
```

Comment: can you show the commands you used to run vault, and the output of `netstat -ntlp` ?

Comment: Thanks Sufiyan. The problem is, that we do not use Vagrant anymore. We have switched to Docker, so my problems are slightly different now.

Comment: please feel free to raise a new question if you have different problem